# How to get image of a PDF page(included text). not images in a PDF page

Tags: java, image, pdf, converters

I have tried a PDF page to image, But just extracted each images in the PDF page. not page image.

Below Code :

```
public class ExtractionPDFtoThumbImgs {

    static String filePath = "/Users/tmdtjq/Downloads/PDFTest/test.pdf";
    static String outputFilePath = "/Users/tmdtjq/Downloads/PDFTest/pageimages";

    public static void change(File inputFile, File outputFolder) throws IOException {
        //TODO check the input file exists and is PDF
        //TODO for the treatment of PDF encrypted
        PDDocument doc = null;
        try {
            doc = PDDocument.load(inputFile);
            List<PDPage> allPages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
            for (int i = 0; i <allPages.size(); i++) {
                PDPage page = allPages.get(i);
                page.convertToImage();
                BufferedImage image = page.convertToImage();
                ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File(outputFolder.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + (i + 1) + ".jpg"));
            }
        } finally {
            if (doc != null) {
                doc.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File inputFile = new File(ExtractionPDFtoThumbImgs.filePath);
        File outputFolder = new File(ExtractionPDFtoThumbImgs.outputFilePath);
        if(!outputFolder.exists()){
            outputFolder.mkdirs();
        }
        try {
            ExtractionPDFtoThumbImgs.change(inputFile, outputFolder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Above code extract images in PDF page. not convert image in PDF page(included text).

Are there converting tools (PDF page to image) or Converting PDFBox class?

Please Suggest how to get image of a PDF page(included text). not to get images in a PDF page.

[image: before converting]

[image: after converting]

Comment: Please share such a PDF. The method 'convertToImage' should do all right, but it may have deficiencies.

Comment: I don't understand the question. convertToImage() is the way to go. Sometimes parts of the text may be missing, this is a problem with type1 fonts. This is solved in the unreleased (but very good) 2.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

Try pdftocairo, it's part of poppler.

I was using imagemagick to convert PDF to images, but it relies on Ghostscript which is sometimes picky about the PDF you feed it so it was hit or miss...

So far pdftocairo has been solid.

http://poppler.freedesktop.org